# Windows Update API CopyToCache(IStringCollection) - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: powershell, com, windows-update, stringcollection

For reducing traffic on our VPN routes, I need to download the windows updates from an external server while reporting to our internal server.

So I'm doing the following:

Create an UpdateSession and Search for Updates, storing them in $SearchResult.
Then I download the Updates from an external Server and then I want to pass them into the Windows Update Api via [IUpdate2.CopyToCache(IStringCollection)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdate2-copytocache)

Everything is just fine, except passing the StringCollection into the Method CopyToCache and it just ends up with an 'Specified cast is not valid.'-Error.

This is my code:

Thank's for help!  eldo-ob

```
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$UpdateCollection = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl

$SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
$AvailibleUpdates = [int16]$SearchResult.Updates.Count

$AvailibleUpdates

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

@($SearchResult.Updates.Item(0).BundledUpdates) | Foreach { 
    $_.DownloadContents | Foreach { 
        $FileName = $_.DownloadUrl.Split("/")[-1]
        $downloadFrom = $_.DownloadUrl.Replace("http://contoso-intern.com","https://contoso-extern.com")
        $WebClient.DownloadFile($downloadFrom,("C:\temp\WSUS\{0}" -f $FileName))
        Write-Host "File Downloaded" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    $StringCollection = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    $StringCollection.Add(("C:\temp\WSUS\{0}" -f $FileName))
    $_.CopyToCache($StringCollection)
}
```

Error Msg:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
At line:24 char:19
+ $_.CopyToCache($StringCollection)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException
```

Update / Solution:

```
# create UpdateSession
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
# create UpdateSearcher
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

# search for updates & count updates
$SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
$AvailibleUpdates = [int16]$SearchResult.Updates.Count

# create an WebClient instance for downloading Updates from alternative source
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

# fix some tls issues (not for everyone neccessary) 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# iterate the updates in searchresult
$SearchResult.Updates | ForEach-Object {
    # iterate bundledupdates
    $_.BundledUpdates | ForEach-Object {
        # create COM stringcollection
        $StringCollection = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.StringColl.1"
        # iterate downloadcontents
        $_.DownloadContents | ForEach-Object { 
            # get the filename from url
            $FileName = $_.DownloadUrl.Split("/")[-1]
            # create external downloadlink
            $downloadFrom = $_.DownloadUrl.Replace("http://contoso-intern.com","https://contoso-extern.com/wsusreplica")
            # download update with webclient
            $WebClient.DownloadFile($downloadFrom,("C:\temp\WSUS\{0}" -f $FileName))
            # adding downloaded filepath to stringcollection
            $StringCollection.Add(("C:\temp\WSUS\{0}" -f $FileName))
        }
        # copy downloaded file to cache (load into wuapi)
        $_.CopyToCache($StringCollection)
    }
}

# create installer
$Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
# set the updates
$Installer.Updates = $SearchResult.Updates
# and install
$Installer.Install()
```

The updates where successfuly installed without using the UpdateDownloader from a self choosen location. So now I'm able to report and search updates through the vpn-tunnel and download the updates from an external source, where we can route the traffic beside the vpn tunnel.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to repeatedly create a collection, add one item to that collection, and then pass that collection as an argument... What kind of argument does `CopyToCache()` expect? Can it accept a plain string (filenmae)? Does it need an array? ) `$StringArray = @(("C:\temp\WSUS\{0}" -f $FileName))`

Comment: After looking at the interface...IUpdate2::CopyToCache(), it needs an IStringCollection intereface...but that is a COM interface. Need to find a COM object that implements the IStringCollection interface. I don't think the .NET object StringCollection implments the IStringCollection interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a .NET object. After searching the registry for the interface, then looking up the TypeLib for the interface, it pointed to the wuapi.dll. I then searched for COM objects that use wuapi.dll as their InprocServer32. I found "Microsoft.Update.StringColl.1". It has an `Add()` method, so it should work the same in the code as your other method (I think). So, replace where you initialize the $StringCollection with this:

```
$StringCollection = new-object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.StringColl.1"
```

Comment: Hey Joseph, thanks for your response. I will try this tomorrow. regards Timo

Comment: Hey Joseph, thanks for the last puzzle piece for my Script. It works fine!